how to resolve proxy error for create react app
npm -v
(node:83232) [DEP0170] DeprecationWarning: The URL http://yourproxyaddress:port is invalid. Future versions of Node.js will throw an error.
(Use node --trace-deprecation ... to show where the warning was created)
10.5.0
I face this error how to resolve this ?
I face this error how to resolve this ?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
